# Hide %2Escriptwsww%2E%3Cscript in js using regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace the script tags from the JSON. I'm currently using the following regex expression:

```
/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi
```

It is only working only in below cases:

```
<script>
<script>adfe</script>
<script>sce
<script>ccrcr<script></script>
<script><dwdwd>
<script></script>
```

I need that it should work on below scenarios:

```
%3Cscript%3Ealert('hug')%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

Here is sample code:

```
var myObj = { "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York","search":"?<script>alert(document.domain)</script>","query":"body<script>alert('fvvr')</script>","path":"/movies?Header:1%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.domain)%3C%2Fscript%3E"};

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '');

alert(myJSON);
```

can you please help me on this?

Comment: Apply regex to *plain* text only. Decode and then re-encode the string after modification.

Comment: You'll have a terrible day when the script includes a string like `let str = "</script>";`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want to match such a sequence:

- Either `<` or `%3C` (hex code for `<`).
- Optionally, either `/` or `%2F` (hex code for `/`), for the closing tag.
- `script` word.
- Either `>` or `%3E` (hex code for `>`).

and replace it with an empty string.

So the intuitive regex is:

```
(?:<|%3C)(?:\/|%2F)?script(?:>|%3E)
```

Note that parts 1, 2 and 4 are enclosed by non-capturing groups,
to set the "borders" of respective alternatives.

Example of usage (with *global* option):

```
var result = source.replace(/(?:<|%3C)(?:\/|%2F)?script(?:>|%3E)/g, "");
```